# Gtest for microcontroller: <avr/io.h> include error

Tags: c++, c, makefile, microcontroller, googletest

I have gtest up and running and confirmed it works with two test projects.

Now I tried including my part of a project written for the ATXMEGA128d4.
If I include my code in my gtest_test file via:

```
extern "C" {
#include "C:\User\my_workspace\active_development\uC_Project\myCode.h"
}
```

I get an error when trying to build my test code: **THE ERROR IS:**

```
C:\User\my_workspace\active_development\uC_Project\Hardware.h(23): 
fatal error C1083: File (Include) cannot be opened: "avr/io.h": No such file or directory
Target //:uC_Project_test failed to build
```

So any include file that has an "avr/io.h" header include, causes a problem as gtest cannot find "io.h" which actually makes sense since io.h does not really exist.
Since the project was developed with Microchip Studio and you are supposed to use:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
```

This tells the Project the IO-pins and other device specific details.
Since the IDE knows its the ATXMEGA128d4 the IDE knows that the required io.h file is the "iox128d4.h" which is in a path of Microchip Studio and somehow communicated to the project, my guess is through the make file.

I have tried replacing all <avr/io.h> with a path to the exact "iox128d4.h" file, but then the project refuses to build at all with the error message "include <avr\io.h> instead of file "..."

**My Question is now:**
How do I let gtest know what include files to use without altering the original project. if I could somehow tell the project to use "iox128d4" instead of <avr/io.h> it should work. Maybe this is possible through the gtest makefile ? I am an absolute beginner in makefiles so I don't even know where to start there.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want to modify the original code you would have to create a mock header for io.h and include that in your test project. This would mean that you have to include a definition and implementation in the mock file for every function, variable and define used in the actual project. The implementation can just be an empty function or return/set a default value. For inspiration you could look at gmock.

Alternativly you could look at structuring the project such that the parts you need to unit test do not depend on any specific hardware includes. As these you are unlikely to be able to test on a development pc or build server. This under the assumption you will not run gtest on your mcu.

Comment: I have made an extra folder in my gtest folder named avr and included a file io.h that has the contents of iox128d4. This part now successfully builds with gtest. There are still some other problems, so I cannot confirm fully if this solved everything, but I can be pretty confident. thank you.

Comment: @uC_dev_imposter Yes I can imagine this would not work the first time around. Mocking hardware can be extensive but once you got it testing will go a lot easier.